# Django edit and delete from front end

Tags: django

Views.py

```
def delete(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=5)
    customer.delete()
    return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

Template.py

```
<form method="POST" action="/customer/">
 <div style="float: right; 
              margin: 0px; padding: 05px; ">
   <p> Name : <select name ="delete_user">
   {% for customer in customer %}
   <option value = "{{ customer }}"> {{ customer.name }} </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="delete"></p>
 </div><br />
```

urls.py

```
(r'^delete/$','quote.excel.views.delete'),
```

This isnot working,it needs to ftch users from database ,in drop down box ,when i select a particular user and click delete,it should delete the name.

This is the error,i m getting

DoesNotExist at /delete/

Customer matching query does not exist.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (to me, at least). Do you mean something like a blog post showing a delete button in the user interface which deletes the blog post from the database?

Comment: @lemonad yep,you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

`all` returns all the customers. use `get` to get only 1 (by id or name)

You need to get the user id. Put that info in your form and handle in the deletion view

Something like

```
data = request.POST.copy()
c_id = int(data.get('id', '0'))
if c_id>0:
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=c_id)
    customer.delete()
```

I recommend to look at teh Django tutorial http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial04/ .That's explain very well how to use forms in Django

Comment: @luc how do,i get the customers name in template

Comment: simply with {{ customer.name }}

Answer (score 0):

Django is a very well documented project. Please take a look at [it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/).

Also refer to the [Model API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/) and [deleting objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete) documentations.

Comment: I never really like "rtfm" answers... i mean, why have SO if that is the case?